# What is the difference between "import" of framework and "linking" with framework?

Tags: swift, import, frameworks, xcode6, core-location

I'm new in Xcode and in Swift language. I'm trying to understand the usage of the "import" in ViewController and the "framework import" in my project. 
Example: if I use *CoreLocation*, need I only import *CoreLocation* in my ViewController, or I need to import *CoreLocation.framework* in my project too? 
I saying this because everything works well only using *import CoreLocation* at the top of my ViewController, without import its framework.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `import` in the source code facilitates compilation of your code, ensuring that the correct headers are found. The "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the "Build Phases" in "Project Settings" (now also included on the "Summary" tab under "Linked Libraries and Frameworks") specifies with which frameworks and libraries your object code will be linked.

Historically we always needed to specify these two separately, but now there is  a project setting "Link Frameworks Automatically", which if on, will automatically link the framework to your project if you `import` it in your source code. You also must have "Enable Modules" turned on, too.

Comment: So I need only to add *import* in my source code without add framework, if "Link Frameworks Automatically" is on?

Comment: Yep, for frameworks. For libraries (e.g. libsqlite3.0.dylib, etc.), you still have to add those manually, but for frameworks, it should add them automatically. Note, you need both "Link Frameworks Automatically" _and_ "Enable Modules" on for this to work.

Comment: Yes, they are both ON. For example: in my app I use MapKit and CoreLocation. Before doing this, I had, in "Capabilities" section, Maps set ON. Now without link framework manually, I have it set to OFF. Is it normal?

Comment: To use maps, I believe you do need to turn on the "Maps" capability. But you shouldn't need to manually add CoreLocation to your list of linked frameworks. Simply having `import CoreLocation` should be adequate (though, to request authorization to determine user's location, you do need to add the appropriate authorization request key in the plist). The entitlements and plist settings are simply a different thing altogether. All the "Link Frameworks Automatically" does is save you from having to manually link to various frameworks, but rather merely import it and you should be good.